# Changing an application's name

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I got the following error from Microsoft when trying to submit my app to the Marketplace,

> The application's name on a device is a generic name "SIXnaApp3", and
>   does not accurately represent the application.

Right now SIXnaApp3 is my project name.  I cannot figure out how to change the application name to meet Microsoft's submission requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solution explorer, Expand the node properties and Open the WMAppManifest.xml file and change the Title of the app. Add things like description,author,company. The following screenshot might help you.
 [image: What need to be changed.]

And this title will change the app name at app menu. If tile menu name is to be changed means, Right click on the project name and go to properties. Change the tile name there.

Solution Explorer > (Right Click)properties > Tile Title

Answer (score 0):

You need an actual application name that is descriptive of what it does. That being said, I looking at the current name, I am assuming that your application is a game. Solution is simple - brainstorm some names for it that is not "**SampleApplication1**" or "**XnaGame1**" (or the like).

Comment: Hi,How do you set the app name??? I thought it was in the xml file cannot find it.

Comment: `App` node, `Title` attribute.